# Unusual prompt in the terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, unix

I have a really unusual prompt in my Unix terminal (I'm using macOS). It looks like this:

```
myUserName@Galaxy-A7-2016
```

I've never seen the `@Galaxy-A7-2016` bit before and I'm worried someone might have poked around my computer but it definitely did not happen. Only way could have been remote.

Comment: That should be your machine's name.

Comment: Is this a laptop with primarily Wi-Fi network access? Have you used something like USB tethering recently? Did it occur after connecting to a specific network?

Comment: @grawity it might be the case that some other phone has been connected, maybe even a Galaxy of some sort. I'm using public WiFi now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is 'prompt'. Usually it consists of username@hostname (the computer's name), so most likely `Galaxy-A7-2016` got configured as your computer name in macOS somehow.

Exactly how it appeared there is mostly speculation (it *could* possibly be discovered from the macOS system logs, but I don't know where the specific logs are located, if they even exist). But my first guess is that it was obtained through DHCP from a buggy router, because DHCP-provided hostnames are a somewhat common source of confusion on macOS systems:

1. Router doesn't have anything yet
2. The "Galaxy A7" phone connects to Wi-Fi and sends a DHCP lease request, adding "my hostname = Galaxy-A7-2016" among the DHCP options.
3. Router issues a new address lease and remembers the provided hostname. (Many home routers store these hostnames so that they could be shown in a "Connected devices" list or similar.)
4. Sometime later, your macOS computer connects to the same network and sends a DHCP lease request.
5. Router tries to find an existing lease and *somehow* selects the lease previously used by the phone.
6. Router issues the address lease, including the hostname it has previously remembered ("your hostname = Galaxy-A7-2016" among the DHCP options).
7. macOS automatically changes its hostname to that provided by DHCP.

I have no idea how step 5 would happen, but nevertheless this is the least unlikely option that I could think of.

Comment: This is close, but not quite correct at steps 5 through 7. macOS tries to determine its hostname via a reverse DNS lookup of its IP address, and if the local DNS server remembers the name of a previous device that happened to get the same IP address from its pool of available numbers, the Mac can effectively inherit the earlier device's name. See [my answer about a somewhat similar situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/42498088#42498088).

Answer (score 1):

How about an update that included the change?

If there is e.g. a $HOME/.bashrc or .bash_aliases in the root home, then you might end up with anything, e.g. those files might contain something similar to:

```
$ env | grep -E 'PS[1-9]+'
PS1=\[\033]0;\w\007\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\w\033[0m\] \s (P)PID=($PPID)$$, s=$?\n${pchar} 
PS4=(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]}\n
```